# How to get URL as a string from xml file?

Tags: java, android, xml, url, xml-parsing

It sounds like a simple question, but I haven't found an answer yet.

I've got an .xml file consists of different items including one URL item. I know the beginning of that URL string item.
What is the easiest way to find this URL among other items and get it as a string?

Here is a class which checks if xml file exists.
If it exists, I should get an url from it.

```
public class ConfigFile {

    private Context context;
    private static String url;

    public ConfigFile (Context _context, String _url){
        this.context = _context;
        this.url = _url;
    }

    public static String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public static void setUrl(String url) {
        ConfigFile.url = url;
    }


    public void checkExistence(){
        File file = new File(context.getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(),"configfile.xml");
        if(file.exists()){
            // here I should paste code which returns url to set it as connection
            //setUrl();
        }
        else{
            //smth
        }

    }
```

Comment: before you get a downvote from people, kindly provide the XML file and also what code you have written so far

Comment: @Deepakkaku I added code I've written. The problem is I'm not sure about other items of xml file, but i know there is going to be an url I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use basic xml parsing framework built into Android.

Basic Android Documentation on XML parsing.
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml

if you find that one to be too complicated, then use one that is based on annotations.
SimpleXML is one I have used in the past and works well.

http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php